# Tape backup with compression

Tags: linux, backup, compression

I would like to backup a NAS to a series of LT02 tapes, (200 gigs uncompressed, 400gigs compressed.) There are about 700 gigs of data to back up. I initially tried cpio, first trying to set hardware compression with an mt -f /dev/nst0 compression and then invoking cpio with: find . -depth -print | cpio -ocBv 2>/root/file_backup > /dev/nst0. It does not appear the compression was set, as four tapes were needed. When I tried:

find . -print -depth -mount | cpio -oCvB 2> /root/file_backup | gzip -c > /dev/nst0 which did compress the backup as expected but at the end of the tape I was not prompted to mount a second tape.

Tar with compression works fine, but you cannot use the multi-tape option with compression. Does someone have and alternate suggestion?

Thank you.

Alan

Comment: I have never has a problem spanning a tar file on Solaris of even older operating systems across multiple tapes.  What makes you think you can conpress over multiple tapes?

Comment: The compression rate is not guaranteed - it depends on your data. For example, video and image files are almost always compressed internally and won't compress any further during a backup. What kind of files are you backing up?

Comment: Spanning across tapes with tar is trivial, but it is not allowed if you are using the 'z' flag or equivalent in order to compress. Most the files I am trying to compress are mp3's. Using gzip and cpio they compress very well, but I obviously don't know which flag to use to allow that combination to allow multi-tapes; I don't get prompted for the device of the tape name.